# SharePoint Integrated Reports missing drop down to manage data sources

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services

I have installed and configured SSRS using SharePoint integrated deployment mode and have been able to successfully run a report from SharePoint.  I created a custom deployment application that will upload all reports and datasets as well as create all data sources and make the proper connections between them when necessary.

I have one report that failed and I need to manually mess with the reports connection to a data source but I found that the drop down does not contain the options to let me manage its shared data sources (see example below).

In this image you can see the option that I am missing.  Please excuse the colors, this is the best image I could find online in a pinch.

[image]

This is only happening in one environment so there must be a configuration change I am not thinking of to show these options.  Here are the things I have already checked:

1. The account I am using is in the sites Owners group and has full control of everything, including the report file.
2. The item is being uploaded as a Document content type for some reason, but I edited properties and changed that to Report Builder Report content type.
3. The Report Server Integration site collection feature has been activated.
4. All of the Reporting Service content types have been added to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turned out to be caused by one of our customizations.  We had an old custom javascript function that was named the same as a SharePoint javascript function that has something to do with those drop down actions.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I would revert to deployment from BIDS to debug this issue.  It will perform some validation during that process and possibly return meaningful errors.